# labeledFor property doesn't work for Text tag

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Can not make labeledFor property work for Text, but it works perfectly for TextField. 
Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private Text text;
@FXML
private Label textLabel;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    textLabel.setLabelFor(text);
}
```

And fxml:

```
<Label ... fx:id="textLabel" text="Sample text"/>
<Text fx:id="text" focusTraversable="true" text=" Hello world"/>
```

It's part of controller class conected to fxml file. Label text should be readed by screen reader but it's not. When I use TextField instead of Text it works correctly. I have already tried approach descibed here: [labelFor field for a Label doesn't function as I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734524/labelfor-field-for-a-label-doesnt-function-as-i-expected) but It doesn't work at all. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I am betting that `Text` gains the focus but there is no indication like when a `TextField` or `Label` gains focus. Try running `System.out.println(primaryStage.getScene().getFocusOwner().toString());` after you think the `Text` should have focus.

Comment: It's is working correctly